# how can i migrate batch to shell?

Tags: shell, jar, scripting, executable-jar

i'm changing code from batch to shell so i have a problem when running the jar 
actually on batch i'm running 
first.bat that contain :

```
call start.bat suites\baseline.xml
```

that call another bat file and pass xml file as an argument and the start.bat : is calling
a jar like this

```
call java -cp arr.jar -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:log/gc.log -Xms4G -Xmx6G -XX:+AggressiveHeap -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=%~dp0/logs -Djava.io.tmpdir=%~dp0/temp org.testng.TestNG %1
```

actually it calls the jar and pass the file already passed by first.bat
on linux environment i did like this

first.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./start.sh "./suites/baseline.xml"
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar "arr.jar" org.testng.TestNG "$1"
```

and the result is 
no main manifest attribute, in arr.jar
can you please help me

Comment: Why classpath option  with `-cp` replaced with `-jar` ?. Did you packaged Manifest file?. If not try with `java -cp /path/to/arr.jar org.testng.TestNG "$1"`

Comment: hey thx for your response i'm on shell linux so instead of -cp I've put -jar i don't need manifest file so i design a main class because the main is generic with the xml file i'm passing as a parameter

Comment: Per this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html , you can use `java -jar app.jar` :: To run an application packaged as a JAR file (requires the Main-class manifest header). What's the result in case if you tried per my earlier comment?